# Dynamic type creation using SimpleNamepace with positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Summary

I've recently become aware of the [`types.SimpleNamespace` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#additional-utility-classes-and-functions), which is [nifty as heck](https://github.com/topper-123/Articles/blob/master/New-interesting-data-types-in-Python3.rst).

It would be useful to create types using this class, but allow them to utilize a signature defining positional arguments instead of keyword only arguments. Allowing positional arguments would give some additional flexibility for instance creation.

<s>My attempts at doing this are not working so I'm looking for suggestions.</s>

### Details

If you subclass `types.SimpleNamespace` utilizing positional arguments, you'll get an error:

```
>>> class Test1(SimpleNamespace):
...  def __init__(self, a, b):
...   super().__init__(a, b)
...
>>> Test1(1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: no positional arguments expected
```

However, you can fix this problem by simply assigning a name to the arguments when calling `super`:

```
>>> class Test2(SimpleNamespace):
...  def __init__(self, a, b):
...   super().__init__(a=a, b=b)
...
>>> Test2(1,2)
Test2(a=1, b=2)
```

Great. But now let's say I want a method to create types like the one above without having to repeat the named arguments in the call to `super().__init__`, using the exact same code as shown to fail above. How can I do it?

EDIT: It turns out my problem was being caused by a simple typo. Everything works with the code shown in the answer below.

Since using `SimpleNamespace`with positional arguments is something others might be interested in understanding how to do, I think it would be a good idea to keep this question instead of closing it.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood the problem correctly - by "dynamically create types" you mean you want to do something like `new_type = make_type('C3', ['a', 'b'])`? Something like that is very rarely a good idea.

Comment: @Rawing I believe it is a great idea in my use case... but I'm also inexperienced. yes that's essentially correct.

Comment: @Rawing I have a list of 30-or-so types that are very inconvenient to define and maintain using standard python syntax. It is much much easier to dynamically create them using some other data structure I have created (a `tuple` of `namedtuples`), and feeding that data structure into the dynamic type creation factory function (i.e., `make_type(name, my_data_structure)`).

Comment: @Rawing Turns out the error was caused by a typo. Didn't see it until this morning. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To more easily create a positional class signature for a child class when the parent class is utilizing a named argument signature, we will create a base class that takes the positional arguments and feeds them into the constructor methods as named arguments.

In order to do this we will need to use `inspect.getargspec`. This will allow us to match up the signature names for `__init__` with the positional values that have been pass into it.

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
import inspect

class PositionalSimpleNamespaceBase(SimpleNamespace):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        args_name = inspect.getargspec(type(self).__init__)[0][1:]
        print('__init__ args: ', args_name)
        super().__init__(**dict(zip(args_name, args), **kwargs))

class ChildClass(PositionalSimpleNamespaceBase):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a, b)
```

Now:

```
>>> obj=ChildClass(1,2)
__init__ args:  ['a', 'b']
>>> obj
ChildClass(a=1, b=2)
```

It works!

If one wishes to *dynamically* create types like this, one way to do that would be using methods similar to those used in the builtin `collections` module for `namedtuple`. One would create a template that subclasses from `PositionalSimpleNamespaceBase`, and then execute the template using the `exec` function.

A simplified version is below (the provided field names are not being sanitized here, so this is not safe to use as shown!):

```
def positional_simple_namespace(name, fields):
    field_names = fields.replace(',',' ').split() if isinstance(fields, str) else tuple(map(str, fields))
    field_text = ', '.join(field_names)
    super_sigs = (f'{n!s} = {n!s}' for n in field_names)
    super_text = ', '.join(super_sigs)
    code = f'''class {name!s}(PositionalSimpleNamespaceBase):
        def __init__(self, {field_text}):
            super().__init__({super_text})
    '''
    namespace = {}
    exec(code, dict(PositionalSimpleNamespaceBase = PositionalSimpleNamespaceBase), namespace)
    cls = namespace[name]
    return cls
```

Use like so:

```
>>> X=positional_simple_namespace('Test', 'a b c')
>>> X(1,2,3)
__init__ args:  ['a', 'b', 'c']
Test(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `inspect.getargspec` is deprecated according to [python 3.8.2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec).